# First order differential equation with initial conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I solved the differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$$

to get the general solution

$$y = \frac{ln|x+1| +c}{2}$$

Im given the initial condition

$$yy' − 2e^x = 0, y(0) = 3$$

but I dont know what to do with it

Comment: You have to set $x = 0$ in your general solution, the whole thing is equal to 3 and then you can compute $c$

Comment: are there two (separate ) problems ?

Comment: I know about that but I dont know what is yy' - 2e^x = 0

Comment: to find a particular solution

Comment: $$yy' = \left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)\prime$$

Answer (score 1):

$$yy'-2e^x=0\\y(0)=3$$ $$ y\frac{dy}{dx}=2e^x\\ydy=2e^xdx$$ now apply integral $$\int ydy=\int2e^xdx\\\frac{1}{2}y(x)^2=2e^x+c\\$$no apply y$y(0)$ to find "c" 
put $x=0$ $$\frac{1}{2}y(0)^2=2e^0+c\\\frac{1}{2}3^2=2+c$$

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like these are two separate questions. You've solved the first one. The second question is to solve

$$y y' - 2e^x = 0, y(0) =3.$$

Rearrange this to

\begin{align}
\int y dy &= \int 2e^x dx\\
y^2/2 &= 2 e^x + c
\end{align}
Since y(0) = 3, you have $3^2/2 = 2 + c$, so $c = 5/2$. So your answer is 
$$y = \sqrt{4 e^x + 5}$$